# Is there a parser for wiki markup language that could create a tree of objects in java

Tags: mediawiki

I'm looking for a parser for the wiki markup language used by wikipedia which can convert the input wiki markup text into a parse tree of java objects. I've come across a few parsers but they parse the markup text into HTML like:

java-wikipedia-parser

Mylyn WikiText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WikiText isn't really set up to be parsed in this way.

What you might consider doing is looking at [Parsoid](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid) – it generates HTML with sufficient annotations that you could convert it into a parse tree.

Otherwise, MediaWiki.org has [a page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) about alternative parsers. It's probably hopelessly out of date, though.